# Approval Process: Word used to approve or reject not understood

Tags: approval-process, approval-step

One of my users is receiving this message when approving something from the Record page: "Your workflow approval message was not processed.  The word used to approve or reject the item was not understood. Please contact your system administrator if you feel you received this message in error." This is strange because she isn't approving via email so I don't think this is an issue of spelling approve/reject wrong etc. I can't seem to find any help online about why this might be happening. Has anyone had this same issue and found the solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It could be due to permissions. Check that your approver has Read/Write permissions on that record. This usually happens with email approvals but could also happens with normal approvals.